# Rules Comparison Operator Is Missing The Direct Input Method

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

I have an "equipment" content type, which has a "manufacturer" field applied to it.  The "manufacturer" field is a taxonomy term reference to a taxonomy which contains all of the manufacturers.

When "equipment" is flagged, I want a "task" to be created.  The problem is, I need different tasks created depending on what manufacturer it is.

Task A applies to manufacturer terms 1,2, and 5.

Task B applies to manufacturer terms 3 and 4.

When I set this up in Rules, I use a "Data Comparison" to check what manufacturer the equipment belongs to.  When I use only one manufacturer, the "Data Comparison" gives me a Direct Input to compare to, I set the comparison operator to "Equals", and I can type in, for example, 2.  Everything works.

However, I want this rule to apply to manufacturers 2, 1, and 5, so I set the comparison operator to "Is One Of".  Suddenly, the Direct Input Method disappears, and I'm sunk.

Is there a way in Rules to compare if a field equals one of several taxonomy terms (OR logic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this problem was that the data comparison was actually comparing against a field belonging to an entity that was referenced to an entity that was referenced to the entity in question.  The structure was: Task -> Ticket -> Equipment: field-manufacturer.

The solution was to specifically declare the field in Rules using "Entity has field".  In this case, I was using two entity references, so I had to use "Entity has field" once to bridge to the first entity, twice to bridge to the second entity, and a third time to identify the particular field on that entity that I wanted to compare data against.

After I set the "Entity has field" conditions in place, I was able to compare data using "is one of" and it gave me a field to type in multiple TIDs.